# what is the correct chunk size for batch application calling stored proc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
  @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<PosRow, Prices>chunk(50)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(new PriceWriter(dao))
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();
    }
```

In my spring batch application, I am reading lines from multiples file each consisting of `3000` lines.

I am processing each line and currently using a `chunk` size of **50**.

After I process, I call my stored procedure in my `write()` for every time. I'd like to understand what should be the `chunk size` I should set for these type of processing that is calling a stored procedure for every line items? Sometimes I observe a lag in processing and writing and I am not sure why. Any suggestings or pointers would really help.

I am also getting different commit count each time when I expect the same number when I run my application:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class StepListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        log.info("Read count, {}", stepExecution.getReadCount());
        log.info("Skip count, {}", stepExecution.getSkipCount());
        log.info("Commit count, {}", stepExecution.getCommitCount());
        log.info("Step {} finished!", stepExecution.getStepName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

the read count and write count remains the same.

I have observed my commit count is higher when I use a chunk size of 1

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend setting the `chunkSize to 20` with `SimpleCompletionPolicy` set.

The below configuration ensures that the commit happens after processing the chunk (i.e. size 20).

```
public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<PosRow, Prices>chunk(new SimpleCompletionPolicy(20))              
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(new PriceWriter(dao))
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();
    }
```

> **Completion Policies:-**
>
> Inside a RepeatTemplate, the termination of the
>   loop in the iterate method is determined by a CompletionPolicy, which
>   is also a factory for the RepeatContext. The RepeatTemplate has the
>   responsibility to use the current policy to create a RepeatContext and
>   pass that in to the RepeatCallback at every stage in the iteration.
>   After a callback completes its doInIteration, the RepeatTemplate has
>   to make a call to the CompletionPolicy to ask it to update its state
>   (which will be stored in the RepeatContext). Then it asks the policy
>   if the iteration is complete.
>
> Spring Batch provides some simple general purpose implementations of
>   CompletionPolicy. SimpleCompletionPolicy allows execution up to a
>   fixed number of times (with RepeatStatus.FINISHED forcing early
>   completion at any time).
>
> Users might need to implement their own completion policies for more
>   complicated decisions. For example, a batch processing window that
>   prevents batch jobs from executing once the online systems are in use
>   would require a custom policy.
>
> ·        **chunk-completion-policy:** A transaction will be committed when
>   this policy decides to complete. Defaults to SimpleCompletionPolicy
>   with the chunk size equal to the commit-interval attribute.
>
> ·        **commit-interval:** The number of items that will be processed
>   before commit is called for the transaction. Set either this or the
>   chunk-completion-policy attribute, but not both.

Comment: with this also my commit count != read count. Read count = 2802 and commitcount after step is 141. When setting chunk size to 1, commit and read count matches

Comment: Commit would happen in batch. In the above case, the calculation is 2800 / 20 = 140. The last commit happens for just 2 remaining records. So the total is 141. Commit happens for every 20 records. It doesn't make sense to  commit for every record processing which will slow the process. The best practice is to commit in batch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct size; you need to determine one that makes sense in your scenario. You could try doing some benchmarks to see where performance rolls off. However, 50 sounds like a reasonable number, and bench marking may not be a good use of your time.